# Unable to edit /etc/apt/sources.list file

Tags: permissions, text-editor, gksu

When I try to edit my sources.list file using the command:

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It requests an administrative password and when I type the password, It says incorrect and try again.What to do? I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using your current password? If so, does your account have administrative privileges? Welcome to AskUbuntu.

Comment: Yes,Iam using my current password and account with administrative privileges. bty using nano editor has resolved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the default terminal text editor program nano instead of gedit to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Alternatively you can also replace `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` with `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Because nano is the default terminal editor in Ubuntu the two commands do exactly the same thing.

The instructions for using nano are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Comment: Unnecessarily wasted 2 hours of time. Resolved.

Answer (score 3):

`gksu` is probably set to use `su` instead of `sudo` as the authentication method. Therefore, it's asking you for the administrative (root) password.

To change this, run `gksu-properties` and choose `sudo` as the Authentication Method. This way, `gksu` will ask you for **your** password.

[image]

You'll notice that the dialog box that asks you for the password changes from:

[image]

which is asking for the **administrative** (root) **password** to:

[image]

which asks for **your password** to perform administrative tasks.

Comment: Yep, This is the reason. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solving the problem:**

If your root password is correct and you are receiving error from using `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` then use `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and go about the changes.

Comment: Why not use simple `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` ? When I do, it open gedit and let me edit the file.

Comment: @ Karel. No, it is gksu that is deprecated in Ubuntu 13.04 not gksudo.

Comment: I guess not. I have tried both out myself -- gksu doesn't work but gksudo works as against your launchpad link. It seems that gksu is deprecated in Ubuntu 13.04. It is clear that until you start using  pkexec gksudo is the right one to use.  There is no argument here though.

Answer (score 0):

In kde you cannot open kate with sudo, ie `# sudo kate <file>`. Instead, you open the file normally, edit it then save. Kate then asks for your password.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have been logged in as root user, the file was effectively not editable. Multiple editors took minutes to only display its content and none of the editors was able to write.

This is most likely to be caused by a swap file at the same location which is locking the file for editing.

In this case, backup the file, delete the original and re-copy the copy.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

You can also delete the file, create a new one and edit / paste the desired content into it, in case you have the text.