# No root privileges when using GUI

Tags: sudo, root, permissions, 13.10

So I'm logged in as the user 'Shannon', but can't gain root access through the GUI when I'm prompted to install a program for example. However using `sudo su`, type in the root password, gain access through the terminal and then install the programs from there. Aren't these passwords supposed to be identical?

Does anyone know how to fix this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: @NikTh: don't agree; the title of his question is misleading. I have updated it.

Comment: @Shannon can you give me an example of what is not working? Please be specific.

Comment: What the OP here wants to achieve. I still not understand. Maybe this is a problem with gksudo ? (sudo mode).

Comment: Yeah, it could be the `gksu` method (I've got a duplicate question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/332669/52726). But the problem is, @Shannon did not specify how he's "installing through the GUI". @Shannon, were you using the `gksu` command to get the "GUI" that's asking for the password? Can you please post a screenshot of the window asking for the password? You can read my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/306898/52726 if that's the window you're getting.

Comment: Related (but *not* a duplicate, this just addresses some of the confusion about how running programs as root works and what user account's password is entered): [How to NOT become a root user? Are administrators root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, let me write a short clarification. There are two different users: `Shannon` and `root`. In Ubuntu, by default, `root` does not have a password *at all* and cannot log in *at all*. If `Shannon` wants to do a task requiring root privileges, he uses the command `sudo` that consults a file called  `/etc/sudoers` and has the ability to turn `Shannon` into `root`.

By default, `sudo` wants to make sure that `Shannon` actually is `Shannon` and not his dog who just took over the keyboard. This is why `sudo` asks user `Shannon` for *his* (and not root's) password. Also note that "a task requiring root privileges" can be a bash shell, which essentially means that you can log in as root (without using root password!).

So, it is not that the two users (`Shannon` and `root`) have different passwords, but that the password of `root` is not actually being asked for *at all*.

Personally, I don't have a dog; that is why I modified `/etc/sudoers` in such a way that it never asks me for my password -- being there is sufficient. Using the command `sudo visudo` I have edited `/etc/sudoers` and edited the following line:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The line above means that all users from the sudo group (and I can only assume that `Shannon` belongs to this group if he installed his system) can run essentially ALL root commands.

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Ah, but now the NOPASSWD directive makes sure that not only I can run any program as root, I can run it without being pestered for typing a password. Note that to edit this file I *must* use the program `visudo` which makes sure that I don't make any syntax error. Syntax error in the `sudoers` file might completely disable the sudo system -- and then, if root does not have a password, you are in a deep kacka.

To add confusion, there is yet another program allowing for gaining root privileges temporarily called `su`. However, `su` is much more primitive -- it just asks for the password *of the root*. Therefore, it *does not work* in a default Ubuntu installation.

So, which password is actually asked for when you type `sudo su`? Well, the command that you are running first is `sudo` , not `su`. Thus, you are asked for `Shannon`'s password, not roots. `sudo` then gains root privileges and runs `su` as root. But when the root runs `su`, `su` does not ask for a password. In any case, don't do that -- that is what `sudo -i` is for (does exactly the same thing).

Comment: Good clarification, but the NOPASSWD is still dangerous.

Comment: @NikTh except that not really :-) if someone can log with your username or if you tend to leave your desktop unlocked and go for lunch, there is little an intruder will not be able to do, starting with a keylogger and ending with `rm -rf /home`. In a single user machine, the really sensitive and valuable stuff is all in your home directory.

Comment: -1 for the recommendation to disable super-user authentication. Not all threats come from people sitting in front of the keyboard, especially if the computer is connected to the internet like yours is (or you wouldn't be writing answers here).

Answer (score 0):

By default root is locked in ubuntu.

To get root privileges we use `sudo su` where it asks for our password.

While installing any software it also prompts for the same password.

To unlock the root account use `sudo -i` and `passwd` in this way you can unlocak root account which is not advised though.

Comment: So let's say I log in as the user 'Shannon' which is not the root user. Performing `sudo -i` will remove the 'authentication' process that comes up on nearly every task?

Comment: No `sudo -i` and `passwd` can be used to unlock the root account which you may have seen is not displayed on login screen. But the best way to do is when you log in as 'Shannon' and install any software when it asks for password give the password of the account 'Shannon' that's it.

Comment: They're the same passwords...

Comment: Ya when you login as the user 'Shannon' its asking for the password of the user 'Shannon'

Comment: @Shannon remember that your password is not the "root" password. User Shannon has his own password. User root has his own password. But by default, the root account is disabled and doesn't have a password. However, by default, **your** account has root privileges (or let's say "admin" privileges), that's why your password can be used to install applications. So yeah, I know you're calling it the "root" password because you can install applications with it, but technically it isn't the "root" password. Read the last link in my comment on the question to know more.