# can not edit grub file, permission issue

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, touchpad

I use to be IT during DOS age, but I admit LUBUNTU is beating me bad.

During the installation of Lubuntu on my old Sony Vaio it did not recognized the touchpad nor my wireless logitech mouse, so I had install it using alt commands and space bar to click. 
On many forums I found a fix editing the grub file in etc/default adding this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp"

I tried FeatherPAD editing unable to save file, then open terminal tried sudo edit with "no permission" error, then tried GKsudo but it seems is not installed by default and I was not able to install it, saying "not found", when the terminal ask me for my password you never get a status message about that input, is this normal in linux? could some one help how to get granted access to edit it?

Comment: Open a terminal, then `sudo nano path-and-name-of-file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to edit /etc/apt/sources.list file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332669/unable-to-edit-etc-apt-sources-list-file)

Comment: It's like a DOS command-line thing, so you shouldn't have any problem when you get the hang of it. The command line version of `sudo edit` in Ubuntu is `sudoedit` (without the space character) which opens the nano text editor terminal program by default in Ubuntu.